# Problem with php and mysql connection xamp

Tags: php, mysql, connection

So I am a user of windows 10 and have xammp in my computer. When I first try to run MySQL server, had problem with 3306 port because I didn't had configured ports free. So I changed it to run on port 3307 and it worked.
After that I am trying to connect to localhost/phpmyadmin, and for a reason I just can't....
Anybody have any advice/idea what is going on ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you change your port number?

Comment: On xampp control panel,  I did this moves: MySqL config -> my.ini -> in the file, I changes the variable port=3306 to port 3307. Do you think this caused the problem ?

Comment: The error you are getting is because the password is wrong, have you tried checking that?

Comment: @FermínRodríguezdelCastillo how can I check which is my password ?

Comment: should be 'root' or '[empty]' if you never set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the xampp config file :  xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc:
ADD THIS LINE

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';]

(I just found the answer, so... I thought would be good to leave this here.. )